# Running EXE with parameters from Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I need help in trying to execute an executable with parameters from my acumatica application.

I want to run a Windows Forms application from screen acumatica. My Windows Forms application is hosted in my local server and the Acumatica website is hosted on Acumatica SaaS platform.

Best regards.

Comment: Answered here - https://community.acumatica.com/customizations-147/running-exe-with-parameters-from-acumatica-5129

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to associate a file type to your program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009412/7376238

Then you can parse the file as a parameter in the main method:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36819292/7376238

In an Acumatica action event handler, throw a file redirection to open the program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796335/7376238

---

Another method is to register a URI scheme handler for your program in Windows:
[URI scheme launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455311/uri-scheme-launching)

Those are special URL that can open a Windows program with parameters. A common example is the 'mailto' URI scheme that opens a email client. Example: `mailto:email@domain.com`

In an Acumatica action event hander, throw a URL redirection to open the program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540253/7376238